# Touch Id prompt buttons localization

Tags: ios, touch-id

I recently integrated Touch Id into my app, using the following framework: https://github.com/auth0/SimpleKeychain.

I have not yet found a way to localize the "Enter Passcode" button in the Touch Id prompt, which is always displayed in English.

Does anyone know how to localize it?

Comment: Is it still displayed in English even when you have changed the language settings for your device? The dialog is presented by iOS, so it should be localised by Apple

Comment: Yes, my device is in French. Also I've seen a screenshot on the web where the text was changed, so it must be possible. Or maybe is it a custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the localizedFallbackTitle property:

Objective-C:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"YOUR TEXT HERE";
```

Swift:

```
var touchIDContext = LAContext()
context.localizedFallbackTitle = "YOUR TEXT HERE"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It appears the framework I used did not allow for the localizedFallbackTitle to be set. I removed it and called the Touch Id prompt manually.

Comment: @BenoîtCaron. You successfully converted the Objective-C code into Swift. Would you mind editing Paul's answer with the translated code?